# What is the best way to load TRT engine for two inference on one GPU?

Tags: tensorrt

I am using TRT6.0.1.5 and 2080Ti GPU, want to loads an engine file

Since I got two cameras doing real-time detection, below is what I have tried

1. loads engine once and using the same deserialized engine to detect
   it will crash eventually
2. loads engine separately to two variables
   the first cameras runs ok and also detect objects normally
   but the second cameras detect nothing， but it did not crash.

How can I correctly loads one engine file and run inference separately on one machine?
Or maybe create different execution context?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the detection on two separate video streams right?
If I were you I'd only change the batch size on the network while you serialize to TensorRT, in this case to two.
Then while running both streams you can use only one network with a different batch size. Something like:

```cpp
tContext->execute(batch_size, inference_buff.data())
```

Where your `inference_buff` will have the data of both image streams.